# NodeJS: How do I generate a random hex key for password reset?

Tags: node.js, express, random

I am developing a express js end point and I need to send some random  hex-decimal code

I am trying to generate a random hex key for a reset password process in nodejs. Can anyone help?
Is there any library? Or shell I use some standard code
Shell I also sign the code like with jwt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let see if I can help

The first way is the js without any library

```js
const randomizer = (length) =>{
  const pullOfChars = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890";
  const generatedArrayOfChars = Array.from(
    { length: length },
    (v, k) => pullOfChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * pullOfChars.length)].toString(16)
  );

  const randomizedString = generatedArrayOfChars.join("");
  return randomizedString
  
}

console.log(randomizer(10))
```

Or you can use the of node js crypto

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const randomString1 = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
console.log(randomString1);
```

hope it helps